# PhantomJS won't send to stdout

Tags: phantomjs, stdout

I have the following script that I'm trying to run with PhantomJS v 1.9.8.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.content =
    "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
    "<html> " +
    "   <head></head> " +
    "   <body> " +
    "       <h1>Test</h1> " +
    "   </body> " +
    "</html>";

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    //page.render('C:\\PDFTemp\\test.pdf', { format: 'pdf' });  // <-- Works
    page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: 'pdf' });  // <- Gives me 0 bytes
    phantom.exit();
};
```

When I run the page.render to write as a file, it works perfectly.  However, rendering to stdout gives me nothing.

Note: I'm running version 1.9.8.  Version 2.0 doesn't like to play nice with ASP.Net, but 1.9.8 works great.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably a bug or limitation of PhantomJS. You could use [`page.renderBase64()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render-base64.html) and decode to a binary string afterwards. No idea if that would work, because encoding is strange in PhantomJS.